# How do I get maven to die gracefully if expected parameters aren't supplied?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm using Maven 3.0.3 on Solaris 10.  How do I get Maven to fail gracefully if the parameters "env" and "label" are not supplied on the command line ?  They would normally be passed in as "-Denv=QA", for example.

These parameters get used in the antrun plugin, where I am exec'ing a few commands under .

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html) would help you.